# Delaying variable declaration in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, system-center

I am trying to finalize a C# / XAML page and am running into trouble. Basically, when I try to compile it is complaining that the name of the variable (Courier_List) does not exist in the current context. I understand by concept why as it has not been declared yet anywhere in the code. However, the reason I have not declared it is because this packaged .dll is meant to work with a management pack (XML file) that contains that definition there (Courier_List) defined as a list and contains the coordinates instructing the visual compiler where to place the list on the form.

I am guessing the solution must be to declare the list variable in the form... but I am not sure how (and if it will work) to just declare the variable and not use it anywhere within the .dll, then when everything is put together it will call the Courier_List from the management pack and not get confused between the two same name variables.

My description may be confusing as it was hard to explain this, so if anyone needs clarification please let me know. I have included the code below:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
namespace Flexity.RMA
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
  /// </summary>
  class RMATask : CreateWithLinkHandler
  {
      public RMATask()
      {
         try
         {
            // Sealed Class GUID
            this.createClassGuid = new Guid("9ebd95da-1b16-b9ea-274d-6b0c16ce1bf3");
            this.classToDelegate = new Dictionary<Guid, CreateLinkHelperCallback>()
            {
                { ApplicationConstants.WorkItemTypeId, new CreateLinkHelperCallback (this.WorkItemCallback) }
            };
         }
         catch (Exception exc1)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(exc1.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
         }
     }

     public void WorkItemCallback(IDataItem RMAForm, IDataItem IncidentForm)
     {
        try
        {
            // Note to self: RelatedWorkItems should be in MP XML as alias under TypeProjections
            if (RMAForm != null && RMAForm.HasProperty("RelatedWorkItems"))
            {
                // Perform Linking
                RMAForm["RelatedWorkItems"] = IncidentForm;
                // Copy Incident Title to RMA Title
                RMAForm["Title"] = IncidentForm["Title"];
                // Copy Incident Description to RMA Description
                RMAForm["Description"] = IncidentForm["Description"];
                // Copy Incident ID to RMA Display Name 
                RMAForm["DisplayName"] = "From " + IncidentForm["Id"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc2.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}

public partial class WITemplate: UserControl
{
    private readonly RelatedItemsPane _relatedItemsPane;

    public WITemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var paneConfig = new WorkItemRelatedItemsConfiguration("RelatedWorkItems", "RelatedWorkItemSource",
                                                           "RelatedConfigItems", "RelatedKnowledgeArticles",
                                                           "FileAttachments");
        _relatedItemsPane = new RelatedItemsPane(paneConfig);
        tabItemRelItems.Content = _relatedItemsPane;
    }

    private void Tracking_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (Courier_List.SelectedValue.ToString())
        {
            case "UPS":

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://wwwapps.ups.com/ietracking/tracking.cgi?loc=CA_CA^&tracknum^=" + Tracking_Num.Text.ToString());
                break;

            case "FedEX":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/index.html?tracknumbers^="+Tracking_Num.Text.ToString()+"^&locale=en_CA^&cntry_code=ca_english");
                break;

            case "UPS SCS":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.upspostsaleslogistics.com/cfw/trackOrder.do?trackNumber^=" + Tracking_Num.Text.ToString());
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You might try another title for this like "declaring a variable via xml after compiling"  Not sure I can be of any more help than that though.

Comment: I dont want to declare it via XML... it ALREADY IS declared in the XML... I am trying to write the logic backend in C# (which also confuses me as to why someone changed the title of my question to XAML) and not sure how to declare it without using the variable until its called from the xml

Comment: It also needs to be defined as a C# class. I recommend that you add part of your XML to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct about the obvious solution. Your button click handler doesn't know about the contents of the management pack XML unless you explicitly connect them.

So, you will need to create a variable for use in your `Tracking_Button_Click` handler for that switch statement. This is a pretty common pattern; if there is a resource somewhere that is needed in C# code you have to have a line or two of code that looks up the resource and assigns it to a variable you declare.

Done correctly, you will not be duplicating data. Rather, the system will set a reference to the existing classes. That in turn will permit you to use the management pack XML in the C# code.

I don't have examples for your management pack, but here are a couple others which follow the pattern. If you want to get at a XAML resource, you do something like:

`var myList = (XAMLResourceType) this.TryFindResource("myResourceKey");`

You don't need exactly this, *but you need something very similar*, in the code in your handler. Then your `switch` statement will work.